# Returning Minimum Value in Binary Tree

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I'm trying to write code that if given a tree, will go through the tree and return the minimum value in that tree, if the tree is empty, it will return val. What I have right now compiles but will not run. Any help?

```
minValue :: Ord a => a -> BTree a -> a
minValue val Empty = val
minValue val (BNode v left Empty) = minimum [minValue v left]
minValue val (BNode v Empty right) = minimum [minValue v right]
minValue val (BNode v left right) = minimum ([minValue v left]++[minValue v right])
```

Comment: Are the elements of the tree ordered, as in a binary search tree?  In any case, you should not need to use lists or `minimum` to do this. In the second and third equation they're superfluous anyway—the minimum of a one-element list is the list's one element.

Comment: The tree is ordered, yes.

Comment: Also: I just tried your function and it has this bug: `minValue 17 (BNode 22 Empty Empty) == 22`

Comment: As per @LuisCasillas' comment: the formulation of this function is a little odd. You probably want to remove the first parameter. Using a `Maybe a` return type may help you cope with Empty trees. Then, at a higher level, you can determine what a reasonable "default" value should be.

Comment: If the tree is a binary search tree, the minimum value is located is the leftmost leaf.

Comment: What does "will not run" mean? When I try it, it runs (after adding a data type declaration).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that `BTree` is defined as

```
data BTree a = Empty | BNode a (BTree a) (BTree a) deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Although for future reference please include data type definitions in your question.

The key to the solution here is that the minimum of a node is the minimum of its value and the mins of each branch:

```
minValue :: Ord a => a -> BTree a -> a
minValue val Empty = val
minValue val (BNode v left right) =
    let leftMin = minValue val left
        rightMin = minValue val right
    in ???
```

Instead of worrying if the left or right is `Empty`, just trust the recursion to handle it.  If `left` is `Empty`, then `minValue val left` will just be `val`, and similarly for `right`.  Then you have 4 values in scope that you want to determine the minimum of, `val`, `v`, `leftMin`, and `rightMin`.  How might you do that?